# show that every continuous real-valued function defined on $S_{\mathbb{\Omega}}$ is eventually constant

Tags: general-topology, ordinals

show that every continuous real-valued function defined on $S_{\mathbb{\Omega}}$ is eventually constant.Where $S_{\mathbb{\Omega}}$ denote the first uncountable ordinal.

There is a hint that for each $\epsilon$,there is an element $\alpha$ of $S_{\mathbb{\Omega}}$  such that $|f(\alpha)-f(\beta)|<\epsilon$ for all $\beta>\alpha$. However, I couldn't figure out how to prove this statement.

Comment: See [Dan Ma's Topology Blog](http://dantopology.wordpress.com/2009/10/11/the-first-uncountable-ordinal/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This result is quite difficult if you don’t know the most basic form of the pressing-down lemma:

> **Lemma.** If $f:S_\Omega\to S_\Omega$ is a pressing-down function, meaning that $f(\alpha)<\alpha$ for each $\alpha\in S_\Omega\setminus\{0\}$, then there is an unbounded $A\subseteq S_\Omega$ on which the function $f$ is constant.

You can find a proof [here](https://www.drmaciver.com/2006/02/the-pressing-down-lemma/), immediately followed by a proof of the result that you want. Before reading those proofs, however, you might like to try using the pressing-down lemma to prove your result. Here’s a hint to get you started: if $f:S_\Omega\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, then for each $n\in\Bbb N$ and $\alpha\in S_\Omega\setminus\{0\}$ there is a $\varphi_n(\alpha)<\alpha$ such that $|f(\beta)-f(\alpha)|<2^{-n}$ whenever $\varphi_n(\alpha)<\beta\le\alpha$. For each $n\in\Bbb N$, $\varphi_n$ is a pressing-down function.

(The full form of the lemma involves the notion of a *stationary set*, a complication that you don’t need here; if you’re interested, you can find it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fodor%27s_lemma).)

Answer (score 4):

I found another simple proof for the hint (in fact, from Munkres's *Topology: A first course*).$\newcommand\abs[1]{\left\lvert#1\right\rvert}$

Suppose that there's some $\epsilon_0>0$ such that for each $\alpha\in S_\Omega$, there's some $\beta>\alpha$ such that $\abs{f(\alpha)-f(\beta)}\ge\epsilon_0$.

Let $\alpha_0=\min S_\Omega$, and given $\alpha_{n-1}$, we denote the corresponding $\beta$ as $\alpha_n$, so increasing sequence $\{\alpha_n\}$ is constructed.

Since $\{\alpha_n\}$ is countable, it's upper-bounded, and since $S_\Omega$ is well-ordered, there's a minimal upper bound $\theta$.

By continuity of $f$, we choose $\beta<\theta$ such that $f((\beta,\theta])\subset(f(\theta)-\epsilon_0/2,f(\theta)+\epsilon_0/2)$. By the minimality of $\theta$, there's an $n$ such that $\beta<\alpha_n\le\theta$, and therefore $\beta<\alpha_n<\alpha_{n+1}\le\theta$, thus $f(\alpha_n),f(\alpha_{n+1})\in(f(\theta)-\epsilon_0/2,f(\theta)+\epsilon_0/2)$, contradicts the hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

> There is at least one point in $\mathbb{R}$ such that the preimage of all of its neighborhoods is uncountable.

You can prove this by covering $\mathbb{R}$ with a sequence of closed intervals of length $1$, picking one with uncountable preimage, and then keep dividing the interval that you are looking at in half and keeping from those halves one that has uncountable preimage.

> There is only one such point in $\mathbb{R}$ for which all its neighborhoods have uncountable preimages

Assume that $a,b$ have the property that all their neighborhoods have uncountable preimages. Take $x_1\in\omega_1$ such that $|f(x_0)−a|<1/1$. Then take $x_2>x_1$ such that $|f(x_2)−b|<1/2$, and so on $x_{n+1}>x_n$ with $|f(x_{n+1})−c|<1/n$, where $c$ alternates between $a$ and $b$ depending on the parity of $n$. Note that the property of $a$ and $b$ allows to find each next term every time, since there are only countably many elements $<x_n$ and uncountably many in the preimage of every neighborhood of $a$ and of $b$.

Since $x_n$ is strictly increasing and countably many, they have a limit $\alpha=\cup_n x_n\in\omega_1$. But then $f(\alpha)$ must be arbitrarily close to both $a$ and $b$. Therefore $a=b$.

> The value $a$ is taken in a tail of $\omega_1$.

The preimage of $\{x:|x−a|>1/n\}$ must be countable, otherwise we could to the same argument above to find a point in it having all its neighborhoods with uncountable preimages. Therefore the preimage of $\{x\neq a\}$ is a countable union of countable subsets of $\omega_1$. This has an upper bound, $\beta$, the union of all those elements.

All ordinals larger than $\beta$ must be mapped to the complement of $\{x\neq a\}$, i.e. $a$.

Comment: This is a very nice proof. +1

Answer (score 1):

Here is another proof, picking up on Yai0Phah's post above in this thread in which he/she showed that for all $\epsilon>0$, there is an $\alpha$ such that $\beta\ge \alpha\Rightarrow |f(\beta)-f(\alpha)|<\epsilon.$

If we take $\epsilon_n=1/n$, we get an increasing sequence $(\alpha_n)$ with the property that $|f(\beta)-f(\alpha_n)|<1/n$ for all $\beta\ge \alpha_n$.

This shows that  that $f(x)=\sup (\alpha_n)$ for all $x\in [\sup (\alpha_n),\omega_1).$

Comment: For the record, this proof can also be found in Munkre's Topology. (the section on Stone-Cech vompactification)

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Here the ordinal $\Omega$ is identified with the set $S_\Omega$ of ordinals $\le \Omega$, in the order topology.
What does a neighbourhood of $\Omega$ look like?  What does continuity of $f$ at $\Omega$ say?

Comment: I see that every neighbourhood of $\Omega$ is uncountable. and continuity of $f$ implies that any preimage of a neighbourhood of $f(\Omega)$ is uncountable. But how to proceed then?

Comment: Continuity says for any $\epsilon > 0$ there is an ordinal $\alpha < \Omega$ such that...  What can you say about the supremum of these $\alpha$'s for a countable set of $\epsilon$'s?

Comment: such that for any x in $(\alpha,\Omega]$, $|f(x)-f(\Omega)|<\epsilon$ ? And then these countably many $\alpha$s has an upper bound $\gamma$? So f is constant on $[\gamma, \Omega]$?

Comment: Yes... the point being that $\gamma$ is a **countable** ordinal, because the union of countably many countable sets is countable.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thank you very much!

Comment: As I read the question, it’s about the space of ordinals strictly less than $\omega_1$, not $\le\omega_1$, so in principle the function need not be continuous at $\omega_1$ (though in fact it will be continuously extensible).