# If $X$ is compact Hausdorff and $p\in X$, then there is a continuous $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ that vanishes at $p$ and nowhere else

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology

Prove or refute:  If $p$ is a point in a compact Hausdorff space $X$ then there exists a continuous real-valued function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ that vanishes at $p$ and nowhere else.

Comment: Hello, welcome to Math.SE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/xQWVb) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3):

HINT: Consider the point $\omega_1$ in the space $\omega_1+1$ with the order topology. [This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428344/show-that-every-continuous-real-valued-function-defined-on-s-mathbb-omega) should help.

**Added:** Here’s a simpler example. Let $X$ be an uncountable set, and let $p\in X$. A set $U\subseteq X$ is open if and only if either $p\notin U$, or $X\setminus U$ is finite. Show that $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space, and that if $f:X\to\Bbb R$ is continuous, and $f(p)=0$, then there are uncountable many points $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=0$.

Comment: What is $\omega_1$?

Comment: @stickyperson: It’s the first uncountable [ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). $\omega_1+1$ is the set of all ordinals less than or equal to $\omega_1$.

Answer (score 1):

I asked a very closely related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180826/in-which-topological-spaces-is-every-singleton-set-a-zero-set) on this site a while back.  The accepted answer shows that a compact Hausdorff space has the property that every singleton set is the zero set of a continuous real-valued function iff it is first countable.  This gives a very clean answer to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb R}$, the uncountable product of a discrete space. The point $0:=(0_i)_{i\in\mathbb R}$ is not the intersection of countably many open sets (otherwise $\{0\}$ would be a so-called $G_\delta$-set), but if there existed such a function, then one could take the preimages of $(-\frac1n,\frac1n)$ and intersect them to obtain $0$.