# Show that continuous function from omega_1 to R is eventually constant

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, cardinals

Let $f: \omega_1 \to \mathbb{R}$ be a contionuous function. Prove that $f$ is eventually constant.

I was trying to prove it by contradiction but I did not have any idea.

Comment: What is $\omega_1$?

Comment: $\omega_1$ is a first uncountable oridinal with order topology

Comment: Hint to get started: can you show that there exists $\alpha_0 < \omega_1$ such that whenever $\alpha_0 \le \beta < \omega_1$ and $\alpha_0 \le \gamma < \omega_1$, then $|f(\beta) - f(\gamma)| < 1$?

Comment: This question does not duplicate the cited question.  The cited question uses the fact that the function $f$ is increasing.  This question is more general because it assumes only that $f$ is continuous.

Comment: There is at least one point in $\mathbb{R}$ such that the preimage of all of its neighborhoods is uncountable. You can prove this by covering $\mathbb{R}$ with a sequence of closed intervals of length $1$, picking the one with uncountable preimage, and then keep dividing it in half and keeping one of the half that has uncountable preimage.

Comment: Now assume that two points $a,b$ have the property that all its neighborhoods have uncountable preimages. Take $x_0\in\omega_1$ such that $|f(x_0)-a|<1/2$ then take $x_2>x_1$ such that $|f(x_2)-b|<1/4$, and so on $x_{n+1}>x_n$ with $|f(x_{n+1})-c|<1/2^n$, where $c$ alternates between $a$ and $b$ depending on the parity of $n$. Note that the property of $a$ and $b$ allows to find each next term, since there are only countably many elements $<x_n$.

Comment: Since $x_n$ is strictly increasing and countably many they have a limit $\alpha$. But then $f(\alpha)$ must be arbitrarily close to $a$ and $b$. Therefore $a=b$. Now, the preimage of $\{x: |x-a|>1/n\}$ must be countable, otherwise we could to the same argument above to find a point in it having all neighborhood with uncountable preimages. Therefore the preimage of $\{x\neq a\}$ is a countable union of countable subsets of $\omega_1$. This has an upper bound. All ordinals larger than that bound must be mapped to $a$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Maybe [show that every continuous real-valued function defined on $S_{\mathbb{\Omega}}$ is eventually constant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/428344/show-that-every-continuous-real-valued-function-defined-on-s-mathbb-omega) is a better  duplicating target?

Comment: @YuiToCheng: Ah, yes, I was thinking of that one, actually. But found the other one first.